# Getting dates from DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

It's my first time using DBpedia and I need to check whether a page is representing a person and if so, I need to extract his birthdate.
The examples on the net have shown where the result outputs entire pages as a result and not single properties.
My input is the link to the DBPedia page

for ex: "*http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cristiano_Ronaldo*".

It should first check if he is a person and if so, get his birthdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with DBpedia, you need to know where exactly to put the restrictions. Basically you need to first say `x is a person` and then say now filter out all the information about x but the `birthDate`:

```
Prefix dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select distinct * where {
?x a dbpedia-owl:Person.
?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?b
} LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Here I am getting the list of all people with their birth-dates. But what I need is provided a link , If it is a person, it should give its birthdate

Comment: You just need to change * to ?b which is the birthDate value. And if you need a specific person, you need to replace ?x with your URI.

Comment: Thank you @artemis, and I just have one more query. I am trying to extract the abstract of a page in english. While I write this code|

`PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?abstract WHERE
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cristiano_Ronaldo> dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
}`

I am getting abstracts in all languages. How to filter it to only english ?

Comment: You need to post another question. I can't explain in a comment. But essentially you need to filter it. `FILTER( LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), "en"))`